# Построение 3d модели по набору изображений

Tags: c++, python, opencv, 3d

Доброго времени суток. Решил заняться построением 3д моделей (или части) по набору изображений (>=2). Прочитал про библиотеку openCV. Вообще представление малое об этом имею, посему нужны советы. С чего начать читать, что использовать? Какие методы? Если я каким-то образом найду облако ключевых точек в 3х мерной плоскости, то как перейти к модели? Триангуляция? Она для 2д вроде. Вообще нужна соответствующая литература. Желательно с примерами. Либо примеры таких программ (python/c++)

Answer (score 4):

"С чего начать читать?".... могу сказать про себя - начинаю читать книги либо с конца либо с середины, хотя слышал некоторые люди начинают читать их с начала (завидую им:)

Если взоры направлены в сторону OpenCV (что безусловно правильно) то читать следует сайт http://opencv.org - оттуда ведут ссылки и на книги, и на примеры, на документацию, на код и так далее.

3D-реконструкция подробно разобрана в классическом культовом фолианте [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision, Richard Hartley / Andrew Zisserman](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf)

Если снимки достаточно качественные а положение камер в момент экспозиции точно известно - 2-х изображений может быть достаточно для восстановления карты глубины.

Триангуляция отдельная тема, она выходит за рамки OpenCV - потребуется отдельный пакет, из открытых есть [cgal.org](http://www.cgal.org/) и [vtk.org](http://www.vtk.org/). Пакеты эти под стать задаче - есть где приложить моцк ;-)

По поводу того что триангуляция только 2D...
Любая геометрическая закономерность, реализованная в 2D-пространстве, имеет бесконечное количество вариантов выражения в 3D-пространстве, так как само 2D-пространство является не чем иным, как одним из бесконечных вариантов плоскости в пространстве, если это Вам не понятно - то может стоит подумать 7 раз прежде чем отрывать HZ? Впрочем, открыв эту книгу, у Вас сразу же возникнут правильные чувства, так как там мало страниц где объем формул составляет менее 20% от объема текста ;-)